# sql for finding sum for each unique timestamp

Tags: sql, join, timestamp, sum, max

Unfortunately, i've been out of the database game for almost 2 years, so i've lost some of my knowledge and am trying to get it back.

I need to get the total of all rows in column A that have an equivalent timestamp (column B).

so, for example, if this is my database:

```
site   |  products |      sell_time
tokyo  |  12       | 2013-02-19 00:01:00
tokyo  |  17       | 2013-02-19 00:01:00
nyc    |  10       | 2013-02-19 00:01:00
dallas |   3       | 2013-02-19 00:02:00
tokyo  |  32       | 2013-02-19 00:03:00
tokyo  |   3       | 2013-02-19 00:03:00
nyc    |  10       | 2013-02-19 00:04:00
```

and i want to know the tally for each of the timestamps for tokyo, i'd want to see

```
site   | num_products |   sell_time
tokyo  | 29           | 2013-02-19 00:01:00
tokyo  | 35           | 2013-02-19 00:03:00
```

Any help is appreciated.  I've lost my edge when it comes to this, and now i've got to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select site,
  sum(products) num_products,
  sell_time
from yourtable
where site = 'tokyo'
group by site, sell_time
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8dc58/2)

Comment: @popnoodles well they did not specify what database they are using and in most if the `site` is present in the select list, then it has to appear in a `GROUP BY`. `Tokyo` appears twice because there are different `sell_time` values.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand it as much as I would like.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT site, SUM(products), sell_time
FROM yourTable
WHERE site = 'tokyo'
GROUP BY sell_time
```

In MySQL the above should work. In SQL Server you would need to add `site` to the GROUP BY, or put something like `MAX(site)` in the `SELECT`.